# How to increment all values in a matrix (list of lists) by n?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must create a function that is passed a matrix as an argument which then increments the value of each item in the matrix by `n` by using nested loops.

e.g if my matrix is `[[8, 9], [4, 6], [7, 2]]` and `n = 1`,
I want the output to be `[[9, 10], [5, 7], [8, 3]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple function to iterate over your list to increment each element by `n` as such:

```
def increment_by_n(lst, n):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            lst[i][j] += n
    return lst
```

With regards to explaining line4: `lst[i][j] += n`, let's explore the following:

```
for i in range(len(lst)): # line 2
    # the above means : for i in [0, 1, 2] 
    # because len(lst) = 3 and hence range(3) = [0, 1, 2]
    # we use this to reference lst[i], i.e lst[0] = [8, 9], lst[1] = [5, 7]
    # Note that lst[0][0] = 8, we will use this below!

    for j in range(len(lst[i])): # line 3
       # first, len(lst[0]) = len(lst[8, 9]) = 2
       # range(2) = [0, 1]
       # so the above means: for j in [0, 1]

       lst[i][j] += n # Line 4
       # We are here referencing the i in [0, 1, 2] and j in [0, 1] in order
       # lst[0][0] = 8 and hence, 8 + 1 = 9
       # lst[0][1] = 9 and hence, 9 + 1 = 10
       # lst[1][0] = 5 and hence, 5 + 1 = 6, and so on...
```

***Note*** that this will modify your initial list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return a new list using a nested list comprehension:

```
def increment_by_n(lst, n):
    return [[col + n for col in row] for row in lst]
```

Usage:

```
>>> increment_by_n([[8, 9], [4, 6], [7, 2]], 1)
[[9, 10], [5, 7], [8, 3]]
```