# Add a number to each element of nested list

Tags: python

I'm working on this code where the user inputs 3 test scores for three different students. The program combines the scores and puts them into `all_scores`. The professor wants to add two extra credits to each score. I'm stuck with nested for loops.

This is what I have to far:

```
all_scores = [m_list[:], a_list[:], s_list[:]]
print("\nAll scores:", all_scores)

for i in range(0, len(all_scores)):
    number = 2
    for j in range(0, len(all_scores)):
        number = number + all_scores[i][j]

print("TEST:", all_scores)
```

**An example:**

All Scores: `[[56.0, 75.0, 19.0], [89.0, 45.0, 98.0], [46.0, 38.0, 98.0]]`

With extra credit: `[[58.0, 77.0, 21.0], [91.0, 47.0, 100.0], [48.0, 40.0, 100.0]]`

Comment: if you import numpy you could just to something like `np.array(all_scores)+2`

Comment: `all_scores[i][j] = number + all_scores[i][j]`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increment all the values in a matrix (list of sublists) by 1 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61831778/6045800)

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension like this:

`[[n+2 for n in sub] for sub in all_scores]`